# nginx E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to install PufferPanel (http://www.pufferpanel.com/v0.8.2/docs)

and when entering the following command

> sudo apt-get install -y openssl curl nginx git mysql-client mysql-server php5-fpm php5-cli php5-curl php5-mysql php5-mcrypt

I get the below error:

```
root@fp-1:/# sudo apt-get install -y openssl curl nginx git mysql-client mysql-server php5-fpm php5-cli php5-curl php5-mysql php5-mcrypt
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
git is already the newest version.
php5-mcrypt is already the newest version.
curl is already the newest version.
mysql-client is already the newest version.
mysql-server is already the newest version.
nginx is already the newest version.
openssl is already the newest version.
php5-cli is already the newest version.
php5-curl is already the newest version.
php5-mysql is already the newest version.
php5-fpm is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 27 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up nginx-core (1.6.2-5ubuntu3.1) ...
Job for nginx.service failed. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript nginx, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package nginx-core (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nginx:
 nginx depends on nginx-core (>= 1.6.2-5ubuntu3.1) | nginx-full (>= 1.6.2-5ubuntu3.1) | nginx-light (>= 1.6.2-5ubuntu3.1) | nginx-extras (>= 1.6.2-5ubuntu3.1); however:
  Package nginx-core is not configured yet.
  Package nginx-full is not installed.
  Package nginx-light is not installed.
  Package nginx-extras is not installed.
 nginx depends on nginx-core (<< 1.6.2-5ubuntu3.1.1~) | nginx-full (<< 1.6.2-5ubuntu3.1.1~) | nginx-light (<< 1.6.2-5ubuntu3.1.1~) | nginx-extras (<< 1.6.2-5ubuntu3.1.1~); however:
  Package nginx-core is not configured yet.
  Package nginx-full is not installed.
  Package nginx-light is not installed.
  Package nginx-extras is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package nginx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nginx-core
 nginx
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm quite new to running a server, so these errors 100% stump me.

Thanks

Comment: Now the real error is visible: Something is wrong with the nginx configuration and it cannot start. Run `nginx -t` to find out what is the problem.

Comment: I ran nginx -t and it gave me:

root@fp-1:/# nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful